# I have tried eveything in my reach but didn't get the result. All i want to get the var lat and lon value from getLocation method

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Location {
  double ? lat;
  double ? lon;

  void getLocation() async {
    Position position = await _determinePosition();
    lat = position.latitude;
    lon = position.longitude;
  }

  Future < Position > _determinePosition() async {
    LocationPermission permission;
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Permission Denied');
      }
    }
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();


  }
}
```

[As you can see the error, i can't even assign the value of lat and lon,and if i put null in there, it will show 0 in result. And i put late then,it waill show runtime error for initiatize the value before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Pb8.jpg)

Comment: are you trying to get the location from map or from the background? Have you added required dependencies in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: Try to follow this link and check if you have missed any steps 
https://mobikul.com/fetch-current-location-in-flutter/

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is :
Add the permission in manifest .
Use permission handler and take permission from user.
After checking that we have permission, use the geolocator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `await` an `async` method, otherwise you don't lknow whether it's done yet. Since you managed to not return a `Future<>`, you cannot `await` your method. Matter of fact you didn't even try, otherwise you would have gotten a compiler error at that point.

```
Future<void> getLocation() async {
  Position position = await _determinePosition();
  lat = position.latitude;
  lon = position.longitude;
}
```

Now you need to find where you call this method and then `await` it. Only then your values will be filled.

Comment: Thanks, It solves the problem, now i can fetch the value of lat and lon from getLocation, but there's one problem now, how can i call the method of getLocation, whenever i tries to print tha getLocation method, it will show Future  instance of getLocation

Comment: Indeed. You need to use `await` to get the actual value from a future. You already did that twice in your code. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63017280/what-is-a-future-and-how-do-i-use-it